# How to retrieve values from RadNumericTextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm sorry for that question but somehow I have a blackout (I know its not a excuse ) but how can I retrieve the value from a `RadNumbericTextBox` using a button to sent the value  (I need a int)

```
<div class="fromRowDiv">
   <asp:Label ID="label1" CssClass="fromLabel" runat="server" Text="From Date" ></asp:Label>
   <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="fromYear" runat="server" MinValue="2000" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" NumberFormat-GroupSeparator="" ></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>   
   <asp:Label ID="Tolabel2" CssClass="fromLabel" runat="server" Text="To Date"></asp:Label>
   <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="toYear" runat="server" MinValue="2000" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" NumberFormat-GroupSeparator=""></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>    
</div>

protected void CalcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            AnnualVacationManager mng = new AnnualVacationManager();

            mng.CalcForNextYear(fromYear,toYear);
}
```

I need the value from RadNumbericTextBox (dynamic )

```
  public AnnualVacationManager() {
    }

    public void CalcForNextYear(int fromYear, int toYear)
    {
        IEnumerable<HtUser> allUsers = HtUser.GetAll();
        List<AnnualVacation> newAnnualVacations = new List<AnnualVacation>();
        if (allUsers.Any()) {
            foreach (HtUser user in allUsers) {
                //int fromYear = 2013;
                //int toYear = 2014;
                IEnumerable<AnnualVacation> usersCurrentAnnualVacation = new List<AnnualVacation>(user.AnnualVacations.Where(a =>a.FromDate.Value.Year >= fromYear && a.FromDate.Value.Year < toYear));
                if (usersCurrentAnnualVacation.Any()) {
                    foreach (AnnualVacation existing in usersCurrentAnnualVacation) {
                        AnnualVacation newAnnualVacation = new AnnualVacation();
                        //Year stuff
                        DateTime newFromDate = existing.FromDate.Value;
                        newFromDate.AddYears(toYear - fromYear);
                        DateTime newToDate = existing.ToDate.Value;
                        newToDate.AddYears(toYear - fromYear);
                        //
                        newAnnualVacation.FromDate = newFromDate;
                        newAnnualVacation.ToDate = newToDate;
                        newAnnualVacation.WorkingTime = existing.WorkingTime;
                        newAnnualVacation.VacationDays = existing.VacationDays + (existing.VacationDays - user.GetBookedVacation(fromYear));

                        newAnnualVacations.Add(newAnnualVacation);

                        newAnnualVacation.HtUser = user;
                    }
                }
            }

            HtEntityFactory.Context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I was pretty solid on the answer until I saw the last word in your post (dynamic).  What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: just not to be static to get the values typed in from the RadNumericTextBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RadNumericTextBox has a Value property on the server-side that returns a nullable decimal (or maybe double) with the numeric value the user entered.  To get the value, provided it has been supplied a valid value, you do:

```
//First .Value returns the nullable decimal or double
//second .Value gets the decimal or double in non-nullable form
fromYear.Value.Value
```

On the client, it should have a `get_value()` method to get it as in:

```
var box = $find("<%= fromYear.ClientID %>");
var val = box.get_value();
```

You may need to format the number in a specific format, so [see this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-numerictextbox-formatting-numeric-values.html) for specifics to how you can tailor the input of numbers, specifically:

```
<NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
```

Supply the values to the method as:

```
mng.CalcForNextYear(Convert.ToInt32(fromYear.Value.Value), 
   Convert.ToInt32(toYear.Value.Value));
```

And that should solve the problem.  You HAVE to have a value in the RadNumericTextBox controls for this to work.  Otherwise, check for null first.

Comment: so      mng.CalcForNextYear(fromYear.Value.Value,toYear.Value.Value); ?

Comment: Yes, to get the non-nullable decimal or double value

Comment: Unless you want it in nullable form (meaning double?), which you can just then use one `.Value`.

Comment: but still get a Argument 1,2 : cannot convert from'double' to 'int' and Error 13 The best overloaded method match for 'HolidayTracker.Code.AnnualVacationManager.CalcForNextYear(int, int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Then you have to change your method to double, or use Convert.ToInt32 to make the value an integer.  If you do that, make sure you specify the number options on the RadNumericTextBox to not allow decimals.  I put a link in my post above to show that.

Comment: Updated above how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int fromyearvalue = convert.toint32(fromYear.text)
int toyearvalue = convert.toint32(toYear.text)

 mng.CalcForNextYear(fromyearvalue ,toyearvalue );
```

OR

```
mng.CalcForNextYear(= convert.toint32(fromYear.totext)),convert.toint32(toYear.totext));
```